# Note for mobile app comment, answer, edits or question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It has been seen that so many stack users are using mobile app to help or ask question on the go. So for any posts (question/answer/edit/comment) that is done through mobile app can we add an Note or Symbolic representation to indicate that the particular post is done from mobile app.

Comment: Posts need to be up to the same quality standards regardless of how they're posted.  Using the mobile app doesn't suddenly mean that the standards are lowered.

Comment: Or just use the right markdown, like `*` for *italics*, `**` for **bold** and '``' for `code`.

Comment: I doesn't mean the same.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think you need to escape the _printed_ back tick with a backslash to prevent it from being a closing element. `\``

Comment: @rya: I tried to...

Comment: What difference does it make in the end?  Who cares whether you posted your question/answer on a phone, your tablet, or your computer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't no if this is a god idea. I mean, who cared if I typed this on an iPhone or not? The qualifying is all that matters in the end. Autocorrect is not an excuse fir poor formatting or the wrong words.

You need to be responsible for the quality of the post no matter what the tool used to write it.

--
Posted from my iPhone.

Comment: Ok sorry and agreed :)

Comment: But... imagine the fun that would come from having a "Posted from IPhone" icon on answers posted to Android questions.

Comment: @TZHX as long as its not "Posted from my Blackberry"

Comment: "[Stack Overflow Now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Now)... how to fix this NPE?"

Comment: @gnat you know Siri is asking when you start seeing [Noel pointer exceptions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8mMf4.jpg)